# Python me da ese error a que se debe

Tags: python

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Taller-Tkinter-master\Ejemplo_Tkinter.py", line 231, in ataque
    result = ataque_aux(i)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Taller-Tkinter-master\Ejemplo_Tkinter.py", line 247, in ataque_aux
    elif(crearmisil(i)):
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Taller-Tkinter-master\Ejemplo_Tkinter.py", line 218, in crearmisil
    move_misilAux(misil, posy, posx)
  File "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Taller-Tkinter-master\Ejemplo_Tkinter.py", line 208, in move_misilAux
    velocidad= random.random(5)
TypeError: random() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Bienvenido user121353 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Saludos, si bien agregas el error que genera tambien es bueno agregar el codigo que lo produjo y explicar lo que has intentado o deseas hacer

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la linea:

```
velocidad = random.random(5)
```

random.random() devuelve un float entre 1 y 0, esta función no acepta argumentos.

Si queres generar un numero entero entre 0 y 5, podrías usar:

```
velocidad = random.randint(0, 5)
```

Si queres generar un float entre 0 y 5, podrías usar:

```
velocidad = random.random() * 5
```

Espero que te sirva